# Is it possible to edit code while running in Visual Studio 2017, even with 'Edit and Continue' enabled?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, edit-and-continue

Frequently I want to change code when the project is running, but am disallowed from doing this because Edit and Continue is enabled.

I assume this is some kind of protective measure, because the changes I make won't apply to the current execution, but I am fine with that. I would like to make them, and then click 'apply' somewhere to make the build update. Is this possible? (It used to be in previous versions of Visual Studio)

Comment: you can only modify the code when it is in break mode while debugging

Comment: Debug > Break All > edit.  Easy peasy.

Comment: Problem is I want to start making changes that dont immediately recompile sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a second instance of Visual Studio, and opening the code file there will allow this to be done.